# IBM Phoneme Detection in Python

Tags: python, ibm-watson

I'm trying to use the [watson developer cloud python library](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk) to interface with the [IBM Speech to Text API](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/text-to-speech) in an effort to detect which phonemes or syllables exist in some text. But I'm running into some issues relating to a required parameter called `customization_id`, and I'm hoping someone might be able to provide more context on what value to pass in. I wasn't able to understand after reading the docs. Here is a code snippet:

```py
from watson_developer_cloud import TextToSpeechV1, WatsonApiException

API_KEY = "<redacted>"
URL = "https://gateway-wdc.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api"

client = TextToSpeechV1(iam_apikey=API_KEY, url=URL)

try:
    #response = client.get_word(customization_id="1", word="HELLO WORLD") 
    #> Malformed GUID: '1'

    #response = client.get_word(word="HELLO WORLD") 
    #> get_word() missing 1 required positional argument: 'customization_id'

    #response = client.get_word(customization_id=None, word="HELLO WORLD") 
    #> ValueError: customization_id must be provided

    #response = client.get_word(customization_id="GA", word="HELLO WORLD") 
    #> ERROR 400: Malformed GUID: 'GA'

    # WHAT VALUE TO USE FOR CUSTOMIZATION_ID ??? ...
    response = client.get_word(customization_id="_______", word="HELLO WORLD") #>

    print("RESPONSE")
    print(type(response))
except WatsonApiException as ex:
    print(f"ERROR {str(ex.code)}: {ex.message}")
```

EDIT: It is possible the expected value is the identifier of a new custom voice model. I've started investigating that strategy [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/issues/639), but unfortunately I'm also running into issues on that one as well. The approach might be something like:

```py
# ...

voice_model_response = client.create_voice_model(
    name="My Custom Model",
    language=LANG,
    description="to get a valid 'customization_id' value..."
).get_result()

customization_id = voice_model_response["customization_id"]

response = client.get_word(customization_id=customization_id, word="HELLO WORLD")

# ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was using the wrong URL and wrong API Key. After fixing the URL to really be "https://gateway-wdc.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api" and creating and upgrading a new standard-level text to speech service and using that service's API Key, I was able to implement the two-step process I mentioned in the updated part of my question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have misread the documentation for the Speech to Text service.

You can create a customisation to modify how a corpus uses pronunciation to detect words

https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text?code=python#add-custom-words

But to do that you need to create a customisation, which you can’t do with a lite account.

https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text?code=python#create-a-custom-language-model

You can use the API to list which customisations you have already created.

https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text?code=python#list-custom-language-models